# kubernetes network topology

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing

I want to have three masters and five workers,
and I want to respond to one million request per second
so my network should design carefully
for a highly available control plane I install:

```
> haproxy
```

and

```
> keepalive
```

on three masters.

But I want the request to go to the worker directly so I need

```
> loadbalancing
```

traffic to 5 workers.
How can I do that?
Please may someone suggest any ideas?

```
> metalLB
```

But I think there should be a simpler way.
Does anyone use:

```
> metalLB
```

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below flow for load balancing the workers

Load balancer------ingress controller - - - - - - - apps running on the workers

Comment: i do not have cloud
how can i make loadbalancer?

Comment: why ingress controller is neede?

Comment: ingress controlller enables entrypoint to all apps running in the cluster

Answer (score 0):

I would use metalLB for providing a service of type loadbalancer, then I would create a ingress controller in order to have just one loadbalancer for the nodes.

MetalLB -->>>> Ingress - >>>>>> Microservice

Answer (score 0):

If you are not running your cluster on a Cloud and you want to have a LoadBalancer, then you will need to use [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/concepts/). This is not complex at all.

You can install MetalLB via Kubernetes Manifest, like:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/metallb/v0.7.3/manifests/metallb.yaml
```

or via Helm Chart

```
helm install --name metallb stable/metallb
```

Then, you will need a MetalLB config file and inside of it, `addresses` parameter should match the IP scheme of the network you are connected to with subnet. LoadBalancer IP addresses will be distributed from this range.
Something like below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: metallb-system
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.240/28
```

I hope it will be useful